# Unable to stream twitter data using storm

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I am following the steps as per the Kantega/storm-twitter-workshop project [link](https://github.com/kantega/storm-twitter-workshop)
but I am stuck at a point. While testing credentials by running the main class in folder cheating

> cd cheating
> mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=storm.starter.CheatingTwitterFunTopology

I am getting the below error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project storm-assignment-solution: Compilation failure
>
> [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
>
> [ERROR] /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/tools.jar
>
> [ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
>
> [ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
>
> [ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
>
> [ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
>
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Error says it all ..

> [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
> [ERROR] /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/tools.jar
>   
>    [ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and

Looking at your project page found the following 

1) It uses 2 maven modules namely `cheating` and `storm-assignment` and both of them are expected to run under Java 1.6 as found in their pom.xml

Check the [pom.xml](https://github.com/kantega/storm-twitter-workshop/blob/master/storm-assignment/pom.xml) for both the module has this

```
    <configuration>
         <source>1.6</source>
         <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
```

Make sure you are running with atleast Java 1.6 or Higher